# gmaps4rails v2 not showing markes at same location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, marker, gmaps4rails2

I am using gmaps4rails in map which shows all users' locations. But if two or more users have the same location there only one marker on the map.
How can I fix this? This my code for building the map:

```
@users=User.where('latitude is NOT NULL') 
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
marker.lat user.latitude 
marker.lng user.longitude 


<script type="text/javascript">
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({internal: {id: 'map'}, provider: {
styles: myStyle
}
},function(){

var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
});</script>
```

Ps: I don't want to view them as a cluster

Comment: I'm pretty sure it adds marker, but it's in exactly the same position so you see it as one. What effect are you expecting?

Comment: You are right it adds the markers. I wasn't really expecting of something specific. Although, I found a feature for gmaps v1 called randomize.  I dont know If this feature can work in v2, but if it does, could I add one marker at this position and the others very close around this one??

Comment: You know, I didn't write this feature and this is first time I hear about it. Why is clustering not an option?

Comment: I want to know which users are in this position. So, I know how to add an infowindow or a title with the user' name but I dont know if I there is a similar option with clustered markers. If Icould list the users of the cluster my problem will be solved.

Comment: Sorry, but this is all explained in gem wiki. Did you even try any of those?

Comment: No, I was following github page & youtube guide. Thank you for the guidance